# Passing today's date in certain format to an html link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem is: I have a 'dynamic' link that I load from an iframe. Here's the code(dynamic because i want to load the link with today's date):

```
<div id="dropdown5" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>SOMETHING</h3>
  <iframe id="orariMilano"src="http://www.trenord.it/it/orari/consulta-orario-ferroviario.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24cp_content%24ctl01%24ucMotoreRisultati_6%24RadioButtonListAndataRitorno=A&ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24cp_content%24ctl01%24ucMotoreRisultati_6%24txtData=**HERE**&ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24......."></iframe>
</div>
```

Where '**HERE**' is the place where i want to put today's formatted date,like "dd/MM/yyyy"

**-** So my question is,can I get today's date and format that into "dd/MM/yyyy" format and pass it to the **link** from a JS or jQuery possibly?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm guessing `trenord.it` is not your site, and that the iFrame has cross-origin content, and if so, *no*, you can't do that.

Comment: It's not, but i don't want to insert something on the site,i just want to replace 'HERE' with today's formatted date.

Comment: Oh, okay, it's rather hard to spot that "HERE" in the really long URL, but **that** you can do, it's just a matter of adding to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var link = "http://www.trenord.it/it/orari/consulta-orario-ferroviario.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24cp_content%24ctl01%24ucMotoreRisultati_6%24RadioButtonListAndataRitorno=A&ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24cp_content%24ctl01%24ucMotoreRisultati_6%24txtData=**HERE**&ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24......";

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
  m = '0' + mm
}
var today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

document.getElementById("orariMilano").src = link.replace("**HERE**", today);
```

```html
<div id="dropdown5" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>SOMETHING</h3>
  <iframe id="orariMilano" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

here is article about date formating with JS [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date). After you do that you can easily adjust the link with pure java script or jquery. Here it is the jquery style.

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

where you can use id instead of "a".